# create workflows at run time WWF

Tags: c#, asp.net, workflow-foundation

I was wondering if there are ways to use Windows Workflow Foundation to
create workflows at run time. I read about dynamic workflows but it is
not wat I want. From what I understood, we are able to modify some
actions and parameters of a workflow at runtime. In my case, I would
like to create a brand new workflow at runtime.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can always create new workflow models and execute them. For example,

```
Sequence wf = new Sequence
{
    Activities = {
        new WriteLine {Text = "Hello"},
        new WriteLine {Text = "World"}
    }
};
WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(wf);
```

You can create workflow XAML and load it to create an workflow.

EDIT:

Check `System.Activities` namespaces in WF4 - the [main System.Activities namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.aspx) allows you to create workflow using code (as opposed to using design surface or XAML). Use 
[WorkflowInvoker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.workflowinvoker.aspx) to invoke such workflow. Essentially, an activity represents the workflow and activity can be composed on several child activities.

You can use `WorkflowApplication` when you need more control - persistance, life cycle events etc. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560894.aspx

Here are few other links that you may find useful:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee342461.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WF/OperationWorkflowInvoker4.aspx

Comment: can you explain it brief. or give some reference link.